# Algorithm needed - benelux contest 2007

Tags: algorithm, algorithmic-trading

This question (last one) appeared in Benelux Algorithm Programming Contest-2007

http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps149s/spring08/problems/bapc07/allprobs.pdf

### Problem Statement in short:

A Company needs to figure out strategy when to - buy OR sell OR no-op on a given input so as to maximise profit. Input is in the form:

```
6
4  4  2
2  9  3
....
....
```

It means input is given for 6 days.
Day 1: You get 4 shares, each with price 4$ and at-max you can sell 2 of them 
Day 2: You get 2 shares, each with price 9$ and at-max you can sell 3 of them 
.

We need to output the maximum profit which can be achieved.

I m thinking about how to go for this problem. It seems to me that if we apply brute force, it will take too much time. If this can be converted to some DP problem like 0-1 Knapsack? Some help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A question titled as "x needed" is probably going to attract some unwanted attention. It sounds too similar to "gimme teh codez" (a very unpopular type of questions here).

Comment: Also, "x needed" induces some fear that a potential answer might be used inappropriately (as in "Yes professor, I made it all by myself").

Comment: It does sound like a DP problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved by DP

suppose there are n days, and the total number of stock shares is m

let f[i][j] means, at the ith day, with j shares remaining, the maximum profit is f[i][j]

obviously, f[i][j]=maximum(f[i-1][j+k]+k*price_per_day[i]), 0<=k<=maximum_shares_sell_per_day[i]

it can be further optimized that, since f[i][...] only depends on f[i-1][...], a rolling array can be used here. hence u need only to define f[2][m] to save space.

total time complexity is O(n*m*maximum_shares_sell_per_day).

perhaps it can be further optimized to save time. any feedback is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your description does not quite match the last problem in the PDF - in the PDF you receive the number of shares specified in the first column (or are forced to buy them - since there is no decision to make it does not matter) and can only decide on how many shares to sell. Since it does not say otherwise I presume that short selling is not allowed (else ignore everything except the price and go make so much money on the derivatives market that you afford to both bribe the SEC or congress and retire :-)).

This looks like a dynamic program, where the state at each point in time is the total number of shares you have in hand. So at time n you have an array with one element for each possible number of shares you might have ended up with at that time, and in that element you have the maximum amount of money you can make up to then while ending up with that number of shares. From this you can work out the same information for time n+1. When you reach the end, then all your shares are worthless so the best answer is the one associated with the maximum amount of money.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like a viable approach. I made a state-diagram, but was unable to decide DP state.

Answer (score 0):

We can't do better than selling the maximum amount of shares we can on the day with the highest price, so I was thinking: (this may be somewhat difficult to implement (efficiently))

It may be a good idea to calculate the total number of shares received so far for each day to improve the efficiency of the algorithm.

Process the days in decreasing order of price.

For a day, `sell amount = min(daily sell limit, shares available)` (for the max price day (the first processed day), shares available = shares received to date).

For all subsequent days, `shares available -= sell amount`. For preceding days, we binary search for `(shares available - shares sold)` and all entries between that and the day just processed = 0.

We might not need to physically set the values (at least not at every step), just calculate them on-the-fly from the history thus-far (I'm thinking interval tree or something similar).